# SWIFT - How do you pass through all data?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an array objects which I want to pass through a segue and use on a conected page.

The first page takes this array and passes it through the segue as below:

```
//home.swift
//Data to pass through
let personInfo:[Person] = [Person(name: "Jess", admin: "jess17", image: "jess17.png", age:"20"), Person(name: "Matt", admin: "matty101", image: "matty101.png", age:"23"), Person(name: "Tom", admin: "thomas9", image: "thomas9.png", age:"21")]

//Segue information

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openAccount" {
        let indexPath = voteCollectionView!.indexPathForCell(sender as CollectionViewCell)
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as AccountPageViewController
        destinationController.peopleData = personInfo
    }
}
```

On the AccountPageViewController the personData array is being caught by:

```
var peopleData:[Person]!
```

However when attaching it to a UILabel I get a nil object error. I have tried to attach it using:

```
headerLbl.text = peopleData[0].name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's time for debugging, see [this tuts](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/debugging-in-ios-essential-tips--mobile-13705). Add the code arraign setting `UILable`. Also at that point print `peopleData` to verify that the data is present. If it is not println `peopleData` in `prepareForSegue `.

Comment: Where are you declaring personInfo?

Comment: Also, double check the spelling of the segue identifier. Perhaps add a breakpoint or log message where you set `peopleData` of the destination and make sure you got to that line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling the `headerLbl.text = peopleData[0].name`.  Are you certain the nil error you are receiving is triggered by the array being nil and not by the actual label being nil?  If you are trying to access the label before your view is actually presented, it will be nil.

Comment: Excellent thanks for all the response. After a little debugging its now passing the data through in one chuck. Thanks again to all